# Iphone webApp Barcode Scanner

Tags: iphone, ios, barcode-scanner, iphone-web-app

I have seen multiple examples of like below:
http://ilevelupapps.com/scanner-go
http://www.pic2shop.com/developers.html

I'm wondering if there is a way or if even possible in my case to have a webApp on an IOS device displaying in full screen to call a barcode scanning tool in the middle of the flow of my App and return the result back to the Current App page, my thoughts are once the Scanner is called my webApp will be replaced with the scanner and the returned Url will open another instance of my WebApp in the browser non fullscreen with the returned Url,
Impossible I take it w/o going Native?, thoughts please.

Noob but was thinking along the lines of calling a Get method in my html to the Url schema and getting a result?, im doubtful.

Thanks!.

Comment: When you say web app are referring to a native iOS app with a webView or an app residing on a webpage being viewed in safari?

Comment: Sorry no not a native IOS webView apologies, I have to build this App on specific hosted platform, I have come to the conclusion this is not possible...

Comment: Ya, what you are asking would open the doorway to unauthorized use of the camera from a webpage which would end up very bad. Unfortunately you are bound by the limits of mobile safari for a full blown web app. The best solution for iOS is to create a hybrid app that opens your page in a UIWebView with very little static native code while your actual content resides on your webpage. That way you have the power of both techs.

Comment: Thanks MarkM I figured this was the Case unfortunately I'm tied to this platform and can't go Native thanks for the response!